# Can't install cgal-qt5 using brew install cgal-qt5

Tags: cgal

I have followed the website of [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html). It told me that I could install it by using the command 
`brew install cgal-qt5`.

But I have received the following error message:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "cgal-qt"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarity named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formula found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in tabs.
```

And when I run the example `draw_triangulation_2.cpp`, it has a fatal error:

`'CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h' file not found`

I guess this result is generated because of the lack of `cgal-qt5`, but I cannot fix it. I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to report a bug to cgal, you may want to [Open an issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/new) on their Github, or browse their [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues)

Comment: did you forget the 5 after qt?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the doc here is wrong. The PR for this was never accepted, and the doc about cgal on brew was published before the cancellation of the PR. On brew, you can install cgal with `brew install cgal` but you won't have the GUI elements in that package until [this PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/52462) is integrated.